# Длительная операция и прогресс в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Пишу приложение на asp.net mvc. Имеется некий action при выполнении которого генерируется отчет. Отчет генерируется достаточно долго и нужно отображать пользователю процесс выполнения, а после завершения генерации пользователь получает файл с отчетом. Собственно вопрос как это сделать?

Comment: почитайте про SignalR: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server

Comment: @Dmitry _"почитайте про SignalR"_ -- для SignalR на клиенте и сервере относительно много всего надо сделать. проще раз в секунду опрашивать сервер о завершении задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы знаете прогресс генерации отчета в цифрах, то можно реализовать следующий вариант. Отправляете запрос на сервер, который запускает генерацию и возвращаете страницу с текстом ожидание, с которой будет Ajax запрос в интервале n-секунд, обновляющем статус на странице. Когда все закончится, отправляйте пользователя на страницу за результатом.

Comment: как то все замудрено, еще и что-то знать надо, чтоб отображать. Думаю ваш ответ можно признать не ответом

Answer (score 0):

если запрос выполняется долго, зачем из пользователя делать заложника просмотра прогресса? Сделайте сообщение пользователю, что процесс генерации достаточно долгий и при обновлении страницы через некоторое время он увидит результат. Генерить отчет оффлайн.